Is there such a thing as 75% lifnei iver?
My question is pretty hypothetical, so I'll try to give an example.
Let's say person A is in a situation where they are committing an aveirah (sin) according to the majority of halachic opinions, yet there is a minority opinion that considers him to not be transgressing.
If person B were to change the situation and render it forbidden according to all halachic opinions, would person B transgress the prohibition of "lifnei iver"?
Do we consider him as having caused person A to have conclusively transgressed, or can person B claim that, according to the majority of opinions, person A was already in a state of transgression and therefore, according to most opinions, he hasn't compounded the transgression in any way?
Fundamentally, I am asking if a stricter, more authorative opinion in halacha at least acknowledges the validity of a lenient, less-authorative opinion, in a situation where the lenient opinion leads to a chumra - viz. lifnei iver.
(For an example of this case, consider somebody leaving a premises in a likely case of yichud - whatever the circumstances need to be to fulfil this hypothetical.)
NOTE: this question asks if it is lifnei iver to cause someone to transgress something that is forbidden according to the way they pasken the halacha. My question is something else.

According to the opinions that it was permitted, it is definitely lifnei iver.
According to the opinions that it was prohibited, nothing has changed.
Is your question whether changing the status from safek to vadai constitutes lifnei iver?

We follow the majority opinion, so it should not be lifnei iver. My question is, does the majority opinion concede that there is a minority opinion to consider at least with regards to lifnei iver, so that even according to the majority opinion, person A has closed off any THEORETICAL avenue of heter and has PRACTICALLY caused person B to transgress?

Welcome to MiYodeya Chani and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
